# Закрыть DialogFragment, кнопкой, из другого Fragment

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

У меня в `DialogFragment` находиться `ViewPager` который отображает 2 `Fragment`а, мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на `View` из `Fragment` закрывался мой `DialogFragment`. Как это сделать?

`DialogFragment`

```
public class DialogProfile extends DialogFragment {

    static WrapContentViewPager viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_profile_tab, container, false);

        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(STYLE_NO_TITLE);
        
        setCancelable(false);
        
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_news_favorites);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        
        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(WrapContentViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentDialogProfile(), "Profile");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentDialogFullInfoProfile(), "FullInfoProfile");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Один из `Fragment`

```
public class FragmentDialogFullInfoProfile extends Fragment
{
    CardView back, close;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_full_info_profile, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

        close = view.findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        });

        back = view.findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int current = DialogProfile.viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if(current != 0) {
                DialogProfile.viewPager.setCurrentItem(current - 1, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру можно попробовать так:

```
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_dialog");
if (prev != null) {
    DialogFragment df = (DialogFragment) prev;
    df.dismiss();
}
```

плюс можно добавить проверки чтобы ничего не упало когда данный диалог не покажется:

```
if (dialogFragment != null
     && dialogFragment.getDialog() != null
     && dialogFragment.getDialog().isShowing()
     && !dialogFragment.isRemoving()) {
            /// hide it
 } else {
     //dialog is not showing
 }
```

если приведенный способ не возымеет результат - есть такой вариант:

```
getDialog().dismiss();
```